# Polynomial addition with exponentiation

Tags: polynomials, exponentiation

I have the following formula:

$$a \times (1+z)^p = b$$

How can I solve for $z$?

Comment: You need to first list some assumptions on what $a,b,p$ are, then decide if you look for real vs. complex solutions, at the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very little effort is required to show that:
\begin{align}
(1 + z)^p &= \frac{b}{a} \\
1 + z &= \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{1/p} \\
z &= \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{1/p} -1
\end{align}

Comment: Couldn't have had a better answer. Thanks a lot. Looks so easy that my initial question almost appears dumb...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a polynomial equation. You need to remember enough about the laws of exponents to solve it.

$$
a(1+z)^p = b
$$
implies
$$
 1+z = (b/a)^{1/p}
$$
so
$$
  z = (b/a)^{1/p} -1 \
$$